# react, self increment with loop

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to make self number increment loop.

The `provider` to reset the number start from 1 again for each component

```
   <ContextProvider>
      <SimpleDiv num={"1"} />
      <SimpleDiv num={"2"} />
    </ContextProvider>
```

I am currently manually put the numbers to the props

the result I want to be

```
block - 1
block - 2
----------------
block - 1
block - 2
block - 3
```

was trying to make the to loop through. But it returns indefinite loop

```
const LoopNum = () => {
  const contextNumber = useContext(Context);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(contextNumber);
  setNumber((num) => num + 1);
  return number;
};
```

Here is the demo.
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-sid-49i1n

The idea is to have the num props have the increment numbers automatically.

eg.

```
const Component1 = () => {
  const newNumber = LoopNum();
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <SimpleDiv num={newNumber} />
      <SimpleDiv num={newNumber} />
    </ContextProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: should they be numbered always from 1  ? or start at the context `number` ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you ask as the linked codesandbox matches exactly what you say you want the result to be. Are you actually trying to increment the state/context value? Or is the context irrelevant and you just want each `SimpleDiv` to maintain its own incremented `num` state? `LoopNum` also isn't valid to use hooks in as it is neither a functional component nor custom hook. What is the source of truth for what number to start incrementing from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`React.Children.map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) and [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to do

```
const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const numberedChildren = React.Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { num: index + 1 })
  );
  return <Provider value={{ number: 0 }}>{numberedChildren}</Provider>;
};
```

Then you can use it like

```
<ContextProvider>
  <SimpleDiv />
  <SimpleDiv />
</ContextProvider>
```

Updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-moon-um9s3?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component that loops the return elements by the number of loop you passed. Like so:

```
import React from "react";

const SimpleDiv = ({ num }) => <div>block - {num}</div>;

const LoopComponent = ({ loopNum }) => {
  return [...Array(loopNum)].map((_, index) => (
    <SimpleDiv key={index} num={index + 1} />
  ));
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LoopComponent loopNum={2} />
      <LoopComponent loopNum={3} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bird-ptxxo